Bathtub too low/trap too high for waste kit, best option?
Found a leak under the tub (highly recommend leak detectors, saved me a ton of trouble), and needed to replace the whole waste/overflow kit. It was already a very tight space, and I am unable to get the slip fit tee that came with the kit low enough to properly align with the drain arm (and if I do, the tub shoe is misaligned and will not seal with the bottom of the tub). I will attach some pictures to demonstrate what/where I am working with.
Rear view of the drain setup:


Drain arm is aligned, but the tub shoe is tilted towards the back of the tub, hindering flow and causing it to leak (rubber gasket removed here, I did install the gasket and try it like this but it leaks around the tub shoe):


The tee is about as low as it can go in the adapter (closeup showing tub shoe side of tee is touching the compression nut on the trap adapter):

Hopefully the pictures are good enough to show my issue. Most of the research I have done has shown this issue in basement bathrooms, but this is a second floor bathroom above a kitchen with drywall ceilings. I'm not sure I could lower the trap without cutting the ceiling and possibly carving into the drywall to get it just a bit lower, but as I understand it, this may cause drainage/slope issues for the rest of the run after the trap anyway. I have also considered having a professional come in and do it all in glued PVC (I assume this is possible for a real plumber?) but I also assume they would want to cut open the kitchen for this and charge a decent amount to do so. Looking for advice on the best way forward, or perhaps a product recommendation I have not considered. Happy to answer questions or add more pictures. Thanks!

Terminology: That's NOT a sanitary Tee. It's a trap slip fit Tee, and the two are very different items.

@Ecnerwal thanks for the correction, I was going off this diagram trying to get the terminology right: https://edmondbathtubrefinishing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Bathtub-Drain-Diagram.jpg.webp But I see how mine is different. I will correct my question

IF (and it does not seem likely here, but it's a common issue) the slip fit Tee is bottoming out on the trap adapter, you trim the end of the slip fit Tee to make it fit right, without trimming so far that it does not seal correctly.
If the trap adapter is too high (which does appear to be the problem here) you need to lower it, however unpleasant that may be, because water does not flow uphill (and that likely is the proximate cause of your initial leak.) Simplest approach here might be to replace the trap itself, given that the whole mess of green glop has no place here. Look for a more compact slip fit adapter than the one you have on there now, or go for a slightly deeper constructed trap (code minimum is 2" from weir to exit, but up to 4" is permitted) so you can drop the inlet. Worst case, you might need to lower the whole line, if the previous worker did the job badly enough; because water does not flow uphill in the pipe past the trap, either. That needs 1/4" per foot slope towards the drain pipe it connects to.

Thanks for the input, I did trim the bottom of the tee a few inches, it's the 'drain arm' of the tee hitting the compression nut on the adapter now. I do worry you're right that the cause of the initial leak was that the slope is off, potentially on the whole run, as it was previously leaking from the trap adapter nut (the previous owners motive for adding the green goo) and it never seemed to drain properly/clogged easily. If I do redo the trap lower, my concern is that right now, the water is just below the trap adapter. If I do it lower, I assume the slip joint being below that is an issue?

Not if the slip joint is properly sealed. But you might also be crossing into the point where you'd be better off with a glued trap (I normally avoid them unless the trap is going into a concrete floor, as you get only one chance to get them right, and there's no adjustment after assembly.) Step zero would be to see how the slope on that line looks right now.

Understood, I'll look into that and give it a bit for anyone else to input, but I'll make sure to accept an answer (probably this) in a few days as I think you're probably correct
